# Apps don't launch in a separate "window"

Tags: launcher

When, for example, I am in the Gmail app reading an email with a link to a movie on IMDB, and I touch the link to open it, the IMDB app launches and displays the correct thing, BUT the IMDB doesn't launch as a separate app! When I display all running apps, this is what I see:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger image)</sup>

IMDB "overtakes" the Gmail "window", and now I can't use both apps at the same time. I want the IMDB app to be in a separate "window". How to do this? Same thing with opening a Youtube link from Chrome, or any other app combination...

The device is Nexus 7 (2013), with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's a feature that I'd love as well - but I don't know of any way to get it on a Nexus 7. If there **is** a way, it'll most likely require root, and probably involve installing a custom ROM or using XPosed Framework. I guess I should ask: Are you willing to void your warranty to get the feature?

Comment: The thing you're looking for a name for that you call a "window" is what Android calls a *task*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a bug, it's a feature. It's called the ["Back Stack"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

The idea is that you perform a single task, like reading e-mail, and all [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), that it's what "windows" are called on Android, are grouped together on the task's back stack.

If you want IMDB "in a separate window", that is as activity of a new task with its own back stack, you can simply open it from the launcher by selecting the IMDB icon.

Comment: I sat staring at this question blankly trying to remember 'Back Stack'. Thanks Flow!